# Expectation of edge weights on the complete graph

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, pr.probability, graph-theory

Let $n,k \geq 3$ be positive integers with $n$ much larger than $k$ and consider a random assignment of weights to the edges of the complete graph $K_n$. On each vertex of $K_n$ we attach a random binary string of length $k$ with equal probability. For each vertex $v$ let $b(v)$ denote the attached binary string. For a binary string $b$, let $x_0(b)$ denote the number of zeroes in $b$ and $x_1(b)$ be the number of one's in $b$. For each pair of vertices $u,v$ put

$$w(\{u,v\}) = \max\{x_0(b(u) + b(v)), x_1(b(u)+b(v))\}$$

Here summation of two binary strings of length $k$ is to be interpreted as summing two elements of $\mathbb{F}_2^k$, say.

Let $X_{n,k}$ denote the random variable

$$X_{n,k} = \max \{ w(\{u,v\}) : u,v \in V(K_n)\}.$$

What is $E(X_{n,k})$ as a function of $n$ and $k$?

Comment: What operation is $b(u)+b(v)$?  Addition as binary numbers?  Element-wise mod 2 addition?

Comment: Since you say "$n$ much larger than $k$" it sounds like you're looking for some sort of asymptotics. Can you say more about which regime you're interested in? The case $n\approx 2^k$ will be very different from the case $n\approx k^2$....

Comment: @BrendanMcKay I have clarified what I mean by summing two binary strings.

Comment: @JamesMartin I believe in the relevant case $k = O(\log n)$, or even a fixed large constant independent of $n$.

Comment: If $k=c\log n$ for constant $c$, then the maximum is $k$ with probability bounded above 0.  If $k$ is a constant, the maximum is $k$ almost surely.

Comment: To flesh that out a bit: If $k=c\log n$ for constant $c$, then the maximum is $k$ with probability bounded above 0.  (I think it is $k$ almost surely, but I don't have a proof.) If $k=o(\log n)$, the maximum is $k$ almost surely.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay are you sure? I agree for $c$ sufficiently small; but say $n=2^{k/4}$. You have order $2^{k/2}$ edges $(u,v)$, and each one gives you a value $w(u,v)=k$ with probability $2^{-(k-1)}$ (if I understand the model). That seems to give you a vanishingly small chance of the maximum being $k$.

Comment: For $k\sim c\log n$, $c$ large enough, I think we're in a "large deviations" regime. We have $\approx e^{ak}$ copies of Binomial($k,1/2$). Look for $\beta$ such that $\frac{1}{k}\log P(\text{Bin}(k,1/2)\geq \beta k) \sim -a$. Then the max of the copies would typically have value around $\beta k$.  This would be sound if the copies were independent. For the non-independent case, you already get an upper bound. Maybe the lower bound could come from a second moment argument? Anyway, in summary I think you will get $E(X_{n,k})\sim \beta k$ for some $\beta=\beta(c)\in(1/2, 1]$, as $k\to\infty$.

Comment: @JamesMartin You are correct. I'll adjust my claim: the maximum is $k$ almost surely if $k=c\log_2 n$ with $c<2$. I'll add a proof in a while.

Answer (score 1):

(Not a complete solution.)

An interesting property is this: For an edge $uv$, the distribution of $b(u)+b(v)$ conditioned on $b(u)$ is the same as the unconditional distribution (namely uniform). From this it follows that for two distinct edges $uv$, $xy$, $w(u,v)$ and $w(x,y)$ are independent even if they have one vertex in common.

Continuing the same logic, the weights are independent for a set of edges that form an acyclic subgraph. I won't use this fact, but applying it to a spanning tree gives probability $\exp(-\Omega(2^{-k}n))$ for the maximum being less than $k$ if $2^{-k}n\to \infty$.

Let $X$ be the random variable equal to the number of edges with weight $k$. Due to the pairwise independence we can easily calculate
$$ \mathbb{E} X = \binom{n}{2}2^{-k+1},\quad
 \mathrm{Var} X = \binom{n}{2}2^{-k+1}(1-2^{-k+1}).$$
As is well known (Chebyshebv's Inequality?) the probability of
a non-negative random variable being zero goes to 0 if $\mathrm{Var} X=o(\mathbb{E} X)^2$. This happens if $2^{-k}n^2\to\infty$.

Using the stronger independence noted above would allow good bounds on central moments of higher order, giving stronger results and possibly the asymptotic distribution of $X$.

Comment: It is not clear to me where you accounted for the fact that one needs to account for the maximum function to give the edge weights... could you please clarify?

Comment: @StanleyYaoXiao  I'm only considering the event that the weight is k, which occurs for 2 of the $2^k$ possible values of $b(u)+b(v)$.  The analysis is the same no matter which two values we are interested in.

Comment: I believe this gives me a good idea for what happens in the regime where $n$ is large compared to $k$. I am also interested in the reverse regime, when $n$ is small compared to $k$; see this question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/421589/expectation-of-edge-weights-on-the-complete-graph-part-2?noredirect=1&lq=1